# MASM error A2006: undefined symbol

Tags: assembly, masm

I am just following along a instructor's video and cannot get rid of the error.
I am hoping I am an idiot and missed something. Please help. Thanks!
My code looks like this:

```
; Title: Poject 00
; Name: Flamo
; Course/Project ID: CS271 
; Description: It will ask for name/age input


.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

DOG_FACTOR = 7

.data ; declare variables here

    userName    BYTE    33 DUP(0) ; string to be entered by user
    userAge     DWORD   ?        ; integer to be entered by user
    intro_1     BYTE    "Hi, my name is Flamo, and I am here to tell you your age in dog years", 0
    prompt_1    BYTE    "What is your name? ", 0
    intro_2     BYTE    "Nice to meet you " , 0
    prompt_2    BYTE    "How old are you? ", 0
    dogAge      DWORD   ?
    results_1   BYTE    "WOW THAT's ", 0
    results_2   BYTE    " IN DOG YEARS!!!!!!!" , 0
    goodbye     BYTE    "BYE BYE! " , 0


.code
main proc ; write your code here

    ; Introduce programmer
    mov edx,    OFFSET intro_1
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf

    ; get user name

    ; get user age

    ; calculate dog years

    ; output results

    ; say goodbye
    mov edx, OFFSET goodBye
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf

    invoke ExitProcess,0

main endp
end main
```

My Error is this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Assembling ..\..\Project00.asm...
1>..\..\Project00.asm(33): error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
1>..\..\Project00.asm(34): error A2006: undefined symbol : CrLf
1>..\..\Project00.asm(46): error A2006: undefined symbol : WriteString
1>..\..\Project00.asm(47): error A2006: undefined symbol : CrLf
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(50,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Sg /WX /Zi /Fo"Debug\Project00.obj" /Fl"Project.lst" /I "c:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta..\..\Project00.asm" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Your code suggests you are trying to use calls to functions available in Kip's Irvine32 library. You'll need to have it installed and then at the top of your ASM program you need `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc`

Comment: Thanks. That just about did it!